# JSONDoc not showing up details about services

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsondoc

JSONDoc is implemented in the spring boot application, services' details are not shown up in the API lists. Screen shot is attached.

[image: The controllers are listed out, the services are listed out, but service details are mising]

The project is multimodule. The dependencies are in web module's pom which have controllers.

```
<!--json doc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsondoc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jsondoc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsondoc-ui-webjar</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

The properties given :

```
jsondoc.version=1.0
jsondoc.basePath=http://localhost:8080
jsondoc.packages[0]=com.auxhouse
```

Comment: I have a similar problem happened http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942398/jsondoc-ui-html-not-loaded-error-404 you have to find a solution ???

Comment: Post up your controller.