# jsondoc-ui.html not loaded, error 404

Tags: jsondoc

I did not should be loaded jsondoc-ui.html, an error 404, although http://localhost:8080/jsondoc works and I get my documents, but without the user interface. Use your instructions http://jsondoc.org/how-to-spring-boot.html please help me understand. Thank you in advance.

my application.properties

```
jsondoc.version=1.0
jsondoc.base-path=http://localhost:8080
jsondoc.packages[0]=backEnd
jsondoc.display-method-as=uri
jsondoc.playground-enabled=true
```

my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jsondoc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsondoc-ui-webjar</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

and use annotaion @EnableJSONDoc in my configuration class